# 呼び出し元のlink_toによって処理を分けたい場合(method: :delete)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

どちらをクリックしても同じアクションを呼びますが、
どちらのlinkから呼ばれたかを判断して処理を分けたいです。

このような場合、どのような方法があるのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

やってみたこと(1)

```
def destroy
    if params[:micropost_type] ='delete'
      @micropost.destroy
      flash[:info] = "目標を諦めました"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url and return
    elsif params[:micropost_type] = 'complete'
      @micropost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "目標を達成しました"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url 
    end
  end

<%= link_to '諦める', micropost, method: :delete, micropost_type: 'delete' ,data: { confirm: "本当に諦めますか"} %>
<%= link_to '達成', micropost, method: :delete, micropost_type: 'complete' %>
```

やってみたこと(2)

```
def destroy
    if params[:delete]
      @micropost.destroy
      flash[:info] = "目標を諦めました"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url and return
    elsif params[:complete]
      @micropost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "目標を達成しました"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url 
    end
  end

<%= link_to '諦める', micropost, method: :delete, name: "delete" ,data: { confirm: "本当に諦めますか"} %>
<%= link_to '達成', micropost, method: :delete, name: "complete" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

私が直すとするとこんな感じです。

```
def destroy
  if params[:type] == 'give_up'
    flash[:info] = '目標を諦めました'
  elsif params[:type] == 'complete'
    flash[:success] = '目標を達成しました'
  end
  @micropost.destroy
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url 
end

<%= link_to '諦める', micropost_path(type: 'give_up'), method: :delete, data: { confirm: '本当に諦めますか' } %>
<%= link_to '達成', micropost_path(type: 'complete'), method: :delete %>
```

ポイントは、

1. 比較は`==`（`=`では代入になってしまう）
2. どっちにしろ`destroy`してリダイレクトするなら、if文の外に出して共通化
3. 通常のルーティングではパスは`xxx_path`となるはず
4. パラメータは`xxx_path`の引数で与えればいい

です。
　余談ですが、本当はモデル名の`micropost`も変更したいところですが、何を指しているのか不明なので、そのままにしてあります。